# Can I configure Django for Unit tests with restricted view on unmanaged databases?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-unittest

We are a small team, trying to work with *Django* with a **restricted access** to a **futurely unmanaged** *PostgreSQL* database (i.e: only views and stored procedures ; no access to any tables) for security reasons.

1. We tried to give (within Postgre) the user **external_test** the rights to create any tables inside his own schema on **external**, and to use the following settings (`settings.py`):

```py
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'external': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgre_db',
        'USER': 'external_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'integration.project.net',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'test_db',
            'USER': 'external_test',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
...
```

2. Using simple passing unit tests (`project/app/tests/test_views.py`):

```py
...
class InternalTest(TestCase):
    database = ['default']

    def test_something(self):
        pass

class StoredProcedureTest(TestCase):
    databases = ['external']    

    def test_one_procedure(self):
        with connections["external"].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.callproc("some_procedure", [42, ])
        pass
...
```

3. If we try the first one with `./manage.py test app.tests.test_views.InternalTest`
   → **ok**
4. If we try the other one with `./manage.py test app.tests.test_views.StoredProcedureTest`
   → **circular dependency issue**
   (`ImproperlyConfigured: Circular dependency in TEST[DEPENDENCIES]`)
   probably because it's skipping the configuration of **default**
5. If we try both tests with `./manage.py test app.tests.test_views`:
   → **permission denied**

   ```sh
   Creating test database for alias 'default'...
   Creating test database for alias 'external'...
   Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database
   ```

   (Django try to create a database **test_db** as the user **external_user**)

We don't really get what Django is trying to do and how to properly configure it.
If we give the rights to **external_user** to create their own databases:

- the database **test_db** is created by **external_user**
- the schema of **default** (sqlite) is created in **test_db** of **external** (postgre)
- the schema of **external** (postgre) is not created in **test_db**

**Questions**

1. Is django able to handle this ?
2. What are we doing wrong ?
3. What is the point of specifying a user **external_user** for *TEST* if in the end django is using the normal user **external_user** ?
4. Why does it write the schema of **default** in **test_db** ? Is there a way to create only models of some apps in it ?
5. Why isn't it able to create the schema of **external** in **test_db** ?

I hope it was described enough. Thank you in advance for your responses =)